# Excel lists analysis

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

How to get in col3 the sum of col2(table2) values, based upon sku? -
Ex: -
sku3 / c / 12-
sku4 / d / 6-

Thank you. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SumIF formula. For example in C3 use this:

```
=SUMIF(E:E,A3,F:F)
```

SUMIF(column to look in, what to look for, if you find it what column is the sum to add up)

Answer (score 0):

This should be migrated over to Superuser.

But the answer is: Put the following formula into C3:C6:

```
=SUMIF(table2[col1], [@col1], table2[col2])
```